# What is the XML namespace for 'xml:whatever'?

Tags: xml, jaxb, xml-namespaces, xml-attribute

I am trying to use JAXB to extract an attribute 'xml:lang' from the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:thr="http://purl.org/syndication/thread/1.0"    xmlns:feedburner="http://rssnamespace.org/feedburner/ext/1.0" xml:lang="en-US" xml:base="http://asmarterplanet.com/wp-atom.php">
```

However, I don't know what the namespace would be for the 'xml' prefix. In the @XmlAttribute annotation for the field, I've tried all of the following:

```
@XmlAttribute(name = "xml:lang")
@XmlAttribute(name = "lang")
@XmlAttribute(name = "xml:lang", namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")
@XmlAttribute(name = "lang", namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")
@XmlAttribute(name = "lang", namespace = "xml")
@XmlAttribute(name = "xml:lang", namespace = "xml")
```

Is there some kind of default namespace when using 'xml' as the prefix?

Comment: FYI: https://github.com/highsource/w3c-schemas/tree/master/atom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the namespace for the `xml` prefix is `http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace`.

Therefore the annotation should be:

```
@XmlAttribute(name="lang", namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace")
```

**For More Information**

- http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace